# awk Sum column from multi-files and put the result in one file

Tags: awk

```
f1
1 5
2 6
3 10
f2
1 8
2 12
3 10
f3 
1 6 
2 9
3 20
```

## i want sum column 2 in

```
f1, f2, f3
```

### and put the result in  f4

```
1 21 30 35
```

i used this command

```
awk '{sum+=$1;}END{print sum;}' f1>f4
```

how can add sum other files

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for adding your efforts in your question. Please do EDIT your question and add more clear samples of your files and output in CODE TAGS and let us know then.

Comment: Can you tell where the `1` from `1 21 30 35` in the result is coming from? or is this just a line number ….?

Comment: Include an empty file in your sample input/output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  if(sum){
    total_sum=(total_sum?total_sum",":"")sum
  }
  sum=""
  header=(header?header",":"")FILENAME
}
{
  sum+=$2
}
END{
  print header ORS total_sum","sum
}
'  file* > file4
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                                  ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==1{                                                ##checking condition FNR==1 which will be TRUE when first line being read.
  if(sum){                                             ##Checking condition if variable sum is NOT NULL then do following.
    total_sum=(total_sum?total_sum",":"")sum           ##Creating variable total_sum  whose value is keep concatenating variable sum value in it.
  }                                                    ##Closing BLOCK for if condition here.
  sum=""                                               ##Nullifying variable sum here.
  header=(header?header",":"")FILENAME                 ##Creating a variable header whose value is keep concatenating awk variable FILENAME value each time cursor here.
}                                                      ##Closing BLOCK for FNR==1 condition here.
{
  sum+=$2                                              ##Creating variable sum whose value is keep adding to $2 value of each Input_file when Input_file is being read.
}
END{                                                   ##Starting END section of this awk code from here.
  print header ORS total_sum","sum                     ##Printing variable header ORS(New line) variable total_sum comma and sum value then.
}
'  file*                                               ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Output will be as follows.

```
file1,file2,file3
21,30,35
```

Comment: please give me any code int order to put all the results in one file

Comment: @Ahmed, Your sample output is NOT clear, please edit your question with correct samples and let us know, thanks.

Comment: @Ahmed, Please check my latest code, just now edited and lemme know then. It gives me the shown output.

Comment: the output in f4 column 2 have sum values of column2 in f1,column  have sum values of column2 in f3, column 4 have sum values of column2 in file 3

Comment: @oguzismail, OP has added his efforts to question and tried his best to explain(being a new joiner), so I thought to answer.

Comment: @Ahmed, I added `> file4` to code now to get output into output file, check now.

Comment: Okay then. Thanks fam I'm flattered

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ f[FILENAME]+=$2; }
  END{ for (i in f) { h=sprintf("%s%s%s",h,sep,i); 
                      d=sprintf("%s%s%s",d,sep,f[i]); sep="," }; 
       print h; print d}' f1 f2 f3 > f4
```

output:

```
$ cat f4
f1,f2,f3
21,30,35
```

The variable `FILENAME` has the value of the filename that is currently read (for input).